# Syntax error in nginx config file

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx on my Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian.

Following [this guide](https://www.pestmeester.nl/index.html) compiled and adapted by Pestmeester I managed to configure http server on port 80 and the site is up and running. I added a file to sites-available, but my server seems to have problems with it, complaining about:

> $ Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed
>   here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com:147 $ nginx: configuration
>   file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com` file's contents:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#       ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /data/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name mysite.com.local mysite.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }


        location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}
        error_log /data/logs/error.log error;
        #error_page 404 /404.html;
        access_log /data/logs/access.log;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        #
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #       fastcgi_index index.php;
        #       include fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#       listen 8000;
#       listen somename:8080;
#       server_name somename alias another.alias;
#       root html;
#       index index.html index.htm;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}

# HTTPS server
#
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

        ssl_certificate          /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key      /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.key;

        #enables all versions of TLS, but not SSLv2 or 3 which are weak and now deprecated.
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        #Disables all weak ciphers
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA$

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        root /data/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /data/www;
        }

        # Error & Access logs
        error_log /data/logs/error.log error;
        access_log /data/logs/access.log;

        location / {
                index index.html index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
                server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

I was also looking into previous posts that had similar error warnings, most of them caused by incorrect indentation or simply omiting a ; at the end of the line. I tried to be cautious and not to repeat such mistakes, but I can't figure out what the problem is. I am grateful for any suggestions how to solve this issue.

Comment: @AD7six your suggestion worked!!! Thanks! I changed the last line from `server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` to `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` and now my site is up and running via https :-) pls post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

After @AD7six suggestion, I changed the nginx config file's last line from `server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` to `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` and now my site is up and running via https.

Answer (score 2):

> This is the part I added

Did you add this into your existing your first server block like so? From the error it suggests you did this:

```
server {
    ... http stuff

    server {
        ...https stuff
    }
}
```

This is not correct syntax, the server blocks must be independant.

```
server {
    ... http stuff
}
server {
    ...https stuff
}
```

You do not include the final file so it's hard to say for sure, but this is what that error means at least.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I have both server blocks separated as you suggested. Please see the entire file I posted in my EDIT.

Comment: That *looks* correct, does it work or are there new errors?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your whole site to run SSL you have to 301 your http traffic to https like so:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.example.com example.com;
       return         301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    www.example.com;

       [... SSL Server Stuff ...]
}
```

This should catch all http requests with or without preceeding www. and redirect all to SSL.